# Accidently activated keyboard input methods

Tags: keyboard, ibus, input

I accidentally activated keyboard input methods and now my keyboard does not respond. I don't know what to do. I'm being forced to use my android to look it up.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Please help! :(

Answer (score 1):

The default keyboard shortcut to enable and disable input methods is <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.
 Once enabled, the default keyboard shortcut to cycle through input methods is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I think it shouldn't have break your keyboard. Can you open a terminal and type
 `gnome-keyboard-properties` to check your keyboard layout?